# @auth0/angular-jwt : Get claims from decoded token

Tags: angular, decode, auth0, jwt, claims

?I get in my Angular 10 application JWT token by "@auth0/angular-jwt". And after decoding function I get a list of claims like this:

```
{
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "johndoe", 
  http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: "Manager", 
  exp: 1525510870, 
  iss: "http://localhost:5000", 
  aud: "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

How I can get custom claims by typescript like:

```
{
  name: "johndoe", 
  role: "Manager", 
}
```

?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> A JWT if made out of 3 parts, you have to decode the one
> from the middle, that is the body containing the claims, the first one
> is a header, and the last one - JWT Signature.

So, having a token we want to get it's claims, so we decode the part from the middle and parse it to json so we will be able to access claims as fields of that object.

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
let decodedJWT = JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

console.log('name: ' + decodedJWT.name);
console.log('role: ' + decodedJWT.role);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your object looks like this:

```
resultObj = {
  name: "", 
  role: "", 
}
```

and one of your SO tags are `Auth0`, you can do this:

```
try {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access-token')!)["AccessToken"];
  const decode = this.jwtHelperService.decodeToken(token);
  let str;
  const newObj = {} as any;
  for (let prop in decode) {
    const val = decode[prop];
    if (prop.includes('/')) {
      str = prop.substring(prop.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, prop.length);
    }
    else {
      str = prop;
    }
    newObj[str] = val;
  }
  this.resultObj = newObj;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: This works for me !

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution:

```
const token = {
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name': "johndoe", 
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role': "Manager", 
  'exp': 1525510870, 
  'iss': "http://localhost:5000", 
  'aud': "http://localhost:5000"
}

const decodedName = token['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name']
const decodedRole = token['http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role']
console.log(decodedName)
console.log(decodedRole)
```